How to find the eigenvector of symmetric tridiagonal matrix
there are several questions related to this topic but only eigenvalues are considered, what about the eigenvectors? consider we have $$T=
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
a & b & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
b & a & b & & \ldots \\
0 & b & a & \ldots & 0 \\
\cdots & & \cdots & & b \\
0 & \ldots & 0 & b & a
\end{array}\right)
$$
I have find the eigenvalues of this matrix according to this paper, but I don't know how to find the eigenvectors, could you please help me?thank you

Assuming $b\neq 0$, the eigenvectors are independent of $a$
and $b$ and given by $v_k=(v_{k1},…,v_{kn})$, where $v_{kj}=\sin(\pi kj/(n+1))$. Here, $n$
is the size of the matrix and $k=1\dots,n$. You can check this using the trigonometric identity $v_{k,j−1}+v_{k,j+1}=2\cos(πk/(n+1))v_{kj}$.
This also makes sense for $j=1$ and $j=n$ if we define $v_{k,0}=v_{k,n+1}=0$.
It then follows that the corresponding eigenvalue is $a+2b\cos(\pi k/(n+1))$.
